# Is there PostgreSQL analogue of CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION (T-SQL)?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to convert some SQL Server stored procedure in a PostgreSQL procedure, but I didn't find PostgreSQL analogue of `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION` (T-SQL). Is it possible to retrieve a value that is associated with the last committed transaction? I will use this value as a synchronization parameter. I will pass this synchronization parameter and table name to the procedure and will compare it with a current change tracking value. If they are different it means that the table was modified and I can do something with modified rows.

Answer (score 1):

After my investigation I would say that we can try to use `pg_last_committed_xact`. It returns `xid` and `timestamp`. We don't need the `timestamp`, but we can use `xid` as an analogue of `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION` (T-SQL). Both of the functions return a new value after DML operations.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I was wrong. We can't use `pg_last_committed_xact` as an equivalent of `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION`.

The `pg_last_committed_xact` value will be incremented after each successful transaction, while the `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION` value will change only when DML operations are applied to tables for which change tracking is enabled.